# sendmail with cat adding extra spaces in email body

Tags: shell, sendmail, cat

When I try to read a file and send email using cat and sendmail,
the email I receive has additional spaces between the letters of words in the text.

My code:

```
export MAILTO="sa@y.com"
export SUBJECT="mydomain PREPROD MONITOR AT ${DATE}"
export BODY1="/usr/local/oracle/wls1036/domains/mydomain/bin/mydomainmonitor/mydomainmonitor.log"

(
  echo "To: $MAILTO"
  echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
  echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
  echo "Content-Type:text/html"
  echo "Content-Disposition: inline"

  cat $BODY1

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $MAILTO
```

Please let me know why these additional spaces are added. When I check the file I don't see any spaces in there.

Comment: The `export` commands are superfluous here -- you only need them if a child process needs access to the environment. A subshell `( command )` sees them because they are interpolated by the current shell when the subshell is spawned.

Comment: agreed and corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the file has long lines, Sendmail needs to break them.

The transparent way to ensure the integrity of data is to use a simple MIME wrapper. You probably want to use a properly MIME-aware MUA to piece together a properly formatted message, but doing it by hand basically amounts to adding a `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` header, and correspondingly QP-encoding the body.

```
MAILTO="sa@y.com"
SUBJECT="mydomain PREPROD MONITOR AT ${DATE}"
BODY1="/usr/local/oracle/wls1036/domains/mydomain/bin/mydomainmonitor/mydomainmonitor.log"

( cat <<____HEADERS
To: $MAILTO
Subject: $SUBJECT
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type:text/html
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

____HEADERS

# Really quick and dirty; does not implement full QP
perl -pe 's/=/=3D/g;s/(.{72})/$1=\n/g' "$BODY1"

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $MAILTO
```

Comment: while I test it, can you please explain 
perl -pe 's/=/=3D/g;s/(.{72})/$1=\n/g' "$BODY1"
what is this doing?

Comment: I tested this and the it doesnt add whitespaces now, instead it is adding "D" in the email:

eg: suppossed to be: HeapFreePercent= 27, but displayed as 
HeapFreePercent= D27

Comment: `s/=/=3D/g` replaces each equals sign with its QP equivalent. `s/(.{72})/$1=\n/g` splits overlong lines by inserting = and a newline every 72 characters.

Comment: If you have access to a proper QP encoder then by all means use that instead.

Comment: based on your suggestion, I broke the line in my output file to multiple lines using \n which resolved the white spaces issue.

Answer (score 0):

I broke the output to my log file into multiple lines using new line char.
Now send mail is sending the email correctly without any additional spaces.